# How do I retrieve automatically generated ID values when adding rows to multiple tables using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a database design for a Gym in SQL Server (ERD at following link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApYj_1gaRPZGgnjOj6VC_HgeaenU).

As part of this I need to be able to create a new member and their first program via a stored procedure. The issue I'm facing is that in order to create a new program, I first need the member number which is automatically generated when a row is added to the Member table, and in order to create a new member, I need to have a payment ID which is automatically generated when a row is added to the payment table.

How do I retrieve the automatically generated identity values in a single stored procedure? i.e. the only way I can see to do this at the moment is to first create a stored procedure to create a row in the Payment table, then manually look the PaymentID value up and then use this value in a separate stored procedure for inserting a row in the Member table (and same again for setting up a new Program).

See below the 3 separate stored procedures I have currently for this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewPayment
    @PaymentType varchar(10),
    @LastPaymentDate date,
    @AmountPaid varchar(15),
    @NextPaymentDate date,
    @AmountDue varchar(15)
AS
    INSERT INTO Payment 
    VALUES (@PaymentType, @LastPaymentDate, @AmountPaid, @NextPaymentDate, @AmountDue);

    IF @@ERROR <> 0 
       RETURN -1 
    ELSE 
       RETURN 0
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE NewMember
    @Name varchar(100),
    @Address varchar(200),
    @ContactNo varchar(15),
    @Email varchar(50),
    @Photo image,
    @PaymentID int,
    @GDPRQ1 char(1),
    @GDPRQ2 char(1),
    @IsDeleted char(1)
AS
    INSERT INTO Members 
    VALUES (@Name, @Address, @ContactNo, @Email, @Photo, @PaymentID, @GDPRQ1, @GDPRQ2, @IsDeleted);

    IF @@ERROR <> 0 
       RETURN -1 
    ELSE 
       RETURN 0
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE NewProgram
    @MemberNumber int,
    @TrainerID int,
    @ProgramStartDate date,
    @TrainerReviewDate date,
    @Active char(1)
AS
    INSERT INTO Program 
    VALUES (@MemberNumber, @TrainerID, @ProgramStartDate, @TrainerReviewDate, @Active);


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERuFS.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value from the stored procedure.  As a general rule, I recommend using the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause for this:

```
create proc NewMember (
    @Name varchar(100),
    @Address varchar(200),
    @ContactNo varchar(15),
    @Email varchar(50),
    @Photo image,
    @PaymentID int,
    @GDPRQ1 char(1),
    @GDPRQ2 char(1),
    @IsDeleted char(1),
    @MemberId_out int output
) As
begin
    declare table @id (memberid int)
    Insert into Members
        output inserted.memberid into @id
        values (@Name, @Address, @ContactNo ,@Email, @Photo, @PaymentID, @GDPRQ1,@GDPRQ2, @IsDeleted);

    select @MemberId_out = memberid from @id;

    return 0
end;
```

The use of `@@ERROR` seems awkward to me (which is one reason I removed it).  If you really want to handle errors, then you want to be using [`TRY`/`CATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) blocks.

.

Comment: Are you sure about `set @MemberId_out = memberid from @id;`? And what's the need for using `OUTPUT` clause and declare a variable while the SP insert only one row & we can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`?

Comment: @Sami . . . (1) This is in a controlled environment which is inserting only one row, so that is okay.  (2) I prefer to stick with "use output" rather than differentiating among the many alternatives, some of which might or might not be appropriate in a given circumstance.

Comment: That isn't okey @GordonLinoff as it'll throw an error _"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'."_. Please correct the syntax error.

Comment: @sami . . . Good morning.  Thank you.  Fixed.